# How to use the Predict Function in R after manually altering a GLM's coefficients

Tags: r, modeling, glm, coefficients

I am creating a GLM model with a number of variables. After I obtain my output I am then using the GLM to predict new values.

I have noticed after manually changing a GLM coefficient for one of the categorical variable's levels I am still getting the same Predicted values even though I know some of my data has this level. Some code might help explain my process:

```
##data frame
df <-data.frame(Account =c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"), 
       Exposure = c(1,50,67,85,250,25,22,89),
       JudicialOrientation=c("Neutral","Neutral","Plaintiff","Defense","Plaintiff","Neutral","Plaintiff","Defense"),
       Freq= c(.008,.5,.05,.34,.7,0,.04,.12),
       Losses = c(100000,100,2500,100000,25000,0,7500,5200),
       LossPerUnit = c(100000,100,2500,100000,25000,0,7500,5200)/c(1,50,67,85,250,25,22,89))


##Variables for modeling
ModelingVars <- as.formula(df$LossPerUnit~df$JudicialOrientation+df$Freq)

##Tweedie GLM
Model <- glm(ModelingVars, family=tweedie(var.power=1.5, link.power = 0),
             weight = Exposure, data = df)
summary(Model)

##Predict Losses with Model coefficients
df$PredictedLossPerUnit <- predict(Model,df, type="response")


##Manually edit a coefficient for one of my categorical variable's levels
Model$coefficients["df$JudicialOrientationNeutral"] <-log(50)

##Predict Losses again to compare
df$PredictedLossPerUnit2 <- predict(Model, df, type ="response")


sum(df$PredictedLossPerUnit)
sum(df$PredictedLossPerUnit2)
View(head(df))
summary(Model)
```

This code works fine and both PredictedLossPerUnits have different numbers (if the row had an observation of "JudicialOrientationNeutral"). When I go to do something similar on my main data set which has more variables but are in a similar fashion (some continuous, some discrete with multiple bins) I keep getting the same predicted values for my predict function even after I manipulate a coefficient.

Is there anything strange that would cause my predict function to continue to give same results as the original - even after I manually changed a coefficient in my GLM?

EDIT: I Found the answer. In my other data set I was doing:
     df$PredictedLossPerUnit <- predict(Model,data=df, type="response")

data isnt actually an argument for the predict function, it should have been "newdata". A silly mistake but a good lesson. Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: Where does the `tweedie()` function come from? I can't run the code. One potential problem is that you should never use "$" inside of formulas if you want to be able to use `predict()` later.

Comment: install.packages("tweedie")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the formula in a manner that detached the meaning from the df object or confused the logic of `predict.lm` or *something*. If you instead run the formula creation the way it was intended to be used (without reference to a data object's name ( so using only column names), you get the desired effect:

```
 ModelingVars <- as.formula(LossPerUnit~JudicialOrientation+Freq)

#----------

> df$PredictedLossPerUnit <- predict(Model,df, type="response")
> 
> 
> ##Manually edit a coefficient for one of my categorical variable's levels
> Model$coefficients["JudicialOrientationNeutral"] <-log(50)
> 
> ##Predict Losses again to compare
> df$PredictedLossPerUnit2 <- predict(Model, df, type ="response")
> 
> df
  Account Exposure JudicialOrientation  Freq Losses  LossPerUnit PredictedLossPerUnit PredictedLossPerUnit2
1       A        1             Neutral 0.008 100000 100000.00000           1549.56677           40213.38196
2       B       50             Neutral 0.500    100      2.00000            919.41825           23860.16405
3       C       67           Plaintiff 0.050   2500     37.31343            169.99221             169.99221
4       D       85             Defense 0.340 100000   1176.47059            565.49150             565.49150
5       E      250           Plaintiff 0.700  25000    100.00000             85.29641              85.29641
6       F       25             Neutral 0.000      0      0.00000           1562.77490           40556.15105
7       G       22           Plaintiff 0.040   7500    340.90909            171.80535             171.80535
8       H       89             Defense 0.120   5200     58.42697            714.15870             714.15870
```

I usually try to keep essential material on screen but here you will need to scroll over to see that the "Neutral" items in the two columns are different.

Edit: I left the creation of the formula outside since it was the least change possible, but a better strategy would have been to use just your formula without the "as.formula" wrapper, which shouldn't be needed and is going to have a different environment for later evaluation. First run: Model <- glm(LossPerUnit~JudicialOrientation+Freq, family = tweedie(var.power=1.5, link.power = 0), weight = Exposure, data = df) and then do your coefficient violence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did get the same results with my code for this test script without making the changes you made to my original. However, when I go to perform this on my real main data set (this was just a fake one I created for the purpose of asking the question). I get the same predicted number even after manipulating the coefficient for "Neutral". I guess it's hard to show since I can't share my entire other data set but I can't figure out why the predict function would give me the same predicted value after manually changing the coefficients exactly like I did here in this test.

Comment: See body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer. In my other data set I was doing:

```
df$PredictedLossPerUnit <- predict(Model,data=df, type="response")
```

"data" isnt actually a function argument for the predict function, it should have been "newdata". A silly mistake but a good lesson. Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: One of the morals of the story then is: present the code exactly as you ran it. I might have seen that error. Also, you should not call entities like `newdata` by the name "functions". They are "formal parameters".

Comment: Good point. Newdata is the name of the parameter in which I pass the argument of "df" into. Thanks again for your help.